# Check javascript generated

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new to Vaadin and I'm developing an application with Vaadin. Vaadin is too funny, but I have an concern about it: How many JavaScript it generates?

I try to explain better my concern. I'm implementing a few panel like this:

[image]

Now I saw that the browser is too slow when load some panel, and I think that the problem could be the quantity of javaScpript generated from client-side engine (I have many listeners on button,comboBox etc ) and I would not have this problem with the increase of members and listeners to block my application.

Then I want to ask you if exist some tools that allow me to check the generated JavaScript?

Are there some best practice to try to avoid these kind of problems?

Comment: The dev tools in any modern browser should let you check the amount of script on the page. Look under "network" or "downloads" for downloaded script and remember to check the page itself for inline script.

Comment: Slow vaadin apps are usually does to too many nested layouts and elements. Try to use a simpler screen layout with less nesting.. (Vaadin compiles your application into GWT code. This code is normally compressed and optimized, so you don't see anything usefull in teh JS debuggers. But you can turn this off. )

Comment: @AndréSchild Then my trouble could be nesting layout instead that too many listeners. Like best practice for the panel above is better using a CssLayout to laying all components instead to use nesting Horizontal,Grid and Vartcal layouts?

Comment: Vaadin 6 oder Vaadin 7? (7 is must faster since it generate less div elements)

Comment: I'm using Vaadin 7.1.11

Comment: You could try using Chrome-browsers devtools to see how the page is generated